Entity Framework Core 8: updating child entities
I’m trying to update a child entity but get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when I call SaveChanges. My organisation (parent) has a list of devices (children). The plan was to get an organisation, add the new device to it, and then update the database.
Thanks in advance.
I'm using Entity Framework Core 8.0.10.
Here's my Handle function:
public async Task<Result> Handle(CreateDeviceCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var organisation = await _organisationRepository.GetAsync(command.OrganisationId);

    if (organisation == null) 
        return Result.Failure(CreateDeviceErrors.NullOrganisation);

    var deviceResult = Device.Create(organisation, command.DeviceId, command.DeviceName);

    if (deviceResult.IsFailure) 
        return Result.Failure(deviceResult.Error);

    var addDeviceResult = organisation.AddDevice(deviceResult.Value);

    if (addDeviceResult.IsFailure) 
        return Result.Failure(addDeviceResult.Error);

    _organisationRepository.Update(organisation);
    
    await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return Result.Success();
}

My Organisation class:
public sealed class Organisation : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Updated { get; private set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; private set; }
    public List<Device> Devices { get; private set; }

    public Result AddDevice(Device device)
    {
        if (Devices.Any(d => d.ExternalDeviceId == device.ExternalDeviceId)) 
            return Result.Failure(OrganisationErrors.DuplicateDevice);

        Devices.Add(device);

        return Result.Success();
    }
}

And my Device class:
public sealed class Device : Entity
{
    public string ExternalDeviceId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Guid OrganisationId { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Updated { get; private set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; private set; }
}

This is the update method in my OrganisationRepository:
public void Update(Organisation organisation)
{
    _context.Organisations.Update(organisation);
}

And the full error:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException : The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Rubicon.Licensing.Infrastructure.LicensingContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\_repos\Rubicon.Platform.Payment\src\Licensing\Rubicon.Licensing.Infrastructure\LicensingContext.cs:line 49
   at Rubicon.Licensing.Application.Devices.Create.CreateDeviceHandler.Handle(CreateDeviceCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\_repos\Rubicon.Platform.Payment\src\Licensing\Rubicon.Licensing.Application\Devices\Create\CreateDeviceHandler.cs:line 39
   at Rubicon.Licensing.Database.Tests.IntegrationTests.CreateDevice() in C:\_repos\Rubicon.Platform.Payment\Rubicon.Licensing.Database.Tests\IntegrationTests.cs:line 101
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.BlockUntilCompleted()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.MessagePumpStrategy.NoMessagePumpStrategy.WaitForCompletion(AwaitAdapter awaiter)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.DelegatingTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (466ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE DATABASE "Licensing";
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (27ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "Organisations" (
          "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
          "Name" text NOT NULL,
          "Created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Updated" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Deleted" boolean NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_Organisations" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "Users" (
          "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
          "AuthenticationId" text NOT NULL,
          "Email" text NOT NULL,
          "Name" text NOT NULL,
          "Created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Updated" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Deleted" boolean NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_Users" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "Subscriptions" (
          "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
          "UserId" uuid NOT NULL,
          "Source" integer NOT NULL,
          "Status" integer NOT NULL,
          "Created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Updated" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_Subscriptions" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
          CONSTRAINT "FK_Subscriptions_Users_UserId" FOREIGN KEY ("UserId") REFERENCES "Users" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "Licenses" (
          "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
          "SubscriptionId" uuid NOT NULL,
          "ProductType" integer NOT NULL,
          "Quantity" integer NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_Licenses" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
          CONSTRAINT "FK_Licenses_Subscriptions_SubscriptionId" FOREIGN KEY ("SubscriptionId") REFERENCES "Subscriptions" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "DeviceLicenses" (
          "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
          "OrganisationId" uuid NOT NULL,
          "LicenseId" uuid NOT NULL,
          "Quantity" integer NOT NULL,
          "Created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Updated" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_DeviceLicenses" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
          CONSTRAINT "FK_DeviceLicenses_Licenses_LicenseId" FOREIGN KEY ("LicenseId") REFERENCES "Licenses" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT "FK_DeviceLicenses_Organisations_OrganisationId" FOREIGN KEY ("OrganisationId") REFERENCES "Organisations" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "PlatformLicenses" (
          "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
          "OrganisationId" uuid NOT NULL,
          "LicenseId" uuid NOT NULL,
          "Created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Updated" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_PlatformLicenses" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
          CONSTRAINT "FK_PlatformLicenses_Licenses_LicenseId" FOREIGN KEY ("LicenseId") REFERENCES "Licenses" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT "FK_PlatformLicenses_Organisations_OrganisationId" FOREIGN KEY ("OrganisationId") REFERENCES "Organisations" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "Devices" (
          "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
          "ExternalDeviceId" text NOT NULL,
          "Name" text NOT NULL,
          "OrganisationId" uuid NOT NULL,
          "Created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Updated" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
          "Deleted" boolean NOT NULL,
          "DeviceLicenseId" uuid,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_Devices" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
          CONSTRAINT "FK_Devices_DeviceLicenses_DeviceLicenseId" FOREIGN KEY ("DeviceLicenseId") REFERENCES "DeviceLicenses" ("Id"),
          CONSTRAINT "FK_Devices_Organisations_OrganisationId" FOREIGN KEY ("OrganisationId") REFERENCES "Organisations" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX "IX_DeviceLicenses_LicenseId" ON "DeviceLicenses" ("LicenseId");
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX "IX_DeviceLicenses_OrganisationId" ON "DeviceLicenses" ("OrganisationId");
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX "IX_Devices_DeviceLicenseId" ON "Devices" ("DeviceLicenseId");
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX "IX_Devices_OrganisationId" ON "Devices" ("OrganisationId");
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX "IX_Licenses_SubscriptionId" ON "Licenses" ("SubscriptionId");
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX "IX_PlatformLicenses_LicenseId" ON "PlatformLicenses" ("LicenseId");
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IX_PlatformLicenses_OrganisationId" ON "PlatformLicenses" ("OrganisationId");
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX "IX_Subscriptions_UserId" ON "Subscriptions" ("UserId");
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (26ms) [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT o."Id", o."Created", o."Deleted", o."Name", o."Updated"
      FROM "Organisations" AS o
      WHERE o."Id" = @__get_Item_0
      LIMIT 1
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?' (DbType = DateTime), @p2='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p3='?', @p4='?' (DbType = DateTime)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "Organisations" ("Id", "Created", "Deleted", "Name", "Updated")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[@p6='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (DbType = DateTime), @p1='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p2='?', @p3='?', @p4='?' (DbType = Guid), @p5='?' (DbType = DateTime), @p11='?' (DbType = Guid), @p7='?' (DbType = DateTime), @p8='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p9='?', @p10='?' (DbType = DateTime)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      UPDATE "Devices" SET "Created" = @p0, "Deleted" = @p1, "ExternalDeviceId" = @p2, "Name" = @p3, "OrganisationId" = @p4, "Updated" = @p5
      WHERE "Id" = @p6;
      UPDATE "Organisations" SET "Created" = @p7, "Deleted" = @p8, "Name" = @p9, "Updated" = @p10
      WHERE "Id" = @p11;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DROP DATABASE "Licensing" WITH (FORCE);

I'm not sure what needs to change here, I've had a good google and am a bit stuck. I can refactor the handler to create the device using a DeviceRepository which I've tested and works fine, but I use this pattern elsewhere and want to make sure I'm not doing something silly.
Does anyone have any ideas?

If you remove generic repository pattern, you will find how it is easy. Anyway, you have to Include Devices when loading Organisation, then organization.Devices.Add(device)  and SaveChanges. No Update calls, which is designed for detached entities.

A few details. First, the Generic Repository is an anti-pattern overtop Entity Framework. EF already provides a Generic Repository in the form of the DbSet<TEntity>. The DbContext already serves as the Unit of Work so in most cases implementing these patterns are completely unnecessary and only serve to get in the way of the most efficient and performant solutions. There is a better than even chance that something in your Repository implementation, especially being a generic pattern, is causing weird behavior or detachments resulting in errors.
For collection navigation properties you want to remove setters entirely and ensure they are initialized:
public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; } = [];

No code should ever replace or re-initialize an entity's collection. This leads to exceptions like what you are seeing and weird behavior. If removing the setter breaks any code, that code is likely going to be responsible for bugs/exceptions.
Next, it is important to distinguish between possessive relationships (one-to-many) and associative relationships. (many-to-many / many-to-one) An example of a possessive relationship would be between a Customer and an Order. If we want to record Orders for  a customer we create a new order and add them to the Customer's Orders collection. An example of an associative relationships would be between an Order and a Product. Orders are made of several products, but we don't want to "create" a product when we add the product to a cart for the order, we want to associate it. The reason I bring this point up is that in your example I see you are passing DeviceId which hints that you have a selection of Devices that you want to associate a given device to the organization rather than create a new device specific to that organization.
Whether associative or possessive, when adjusting a collection under an entity you want to ensure that when you load that parent entity, you eager load the collection to add or remove items from.
var organisation = await _context.Organisations
    .Include(x => x.Devices)
    .SingleAsync(x => x.OrganisationId == command.OrganisationId);

Next, if the relationship is possessive, you would create an add a Device similar to how you had done:
var device = new Device(command.DeviceName);
organisation.Devices.Add(device);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

Ideally PK generation for new entities should be managed by the database, not in code. If instead the DeviceId passed was a reference to an existing Device and this relationship is associative:
if (!organisation.Devices.Any(x => x.DeviceId == command.DeviceId))
{
    var device = await _context.Devices
        .SingleAsync(x => x.DeviceId == command.DeviceId);
    organisation.Devices.Add(device);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
} 

We don't create an instance to represent an existing device as EF would want to treat this as an insert. Instead we fetch the Device and append it to the organisation. This also serves as a validation that the passed device ID was valid.
There is no "possessive" or "associative" relationship difference in EF/databases, it is merely a construct for thinking about the relationship. In the case of a many-to-one, you can still have a possessive relationship that changes the ownership of an existing record. For instance a Folder Tree structure with a Parent where you want to move one folder into a new parent. In this case it is equally important that the DbContext is working with the references to the affected entities and not try to save reads etc. by new-ing up instances to represent existing data rows. When you "move" a tracked reference from one tracked instance to another tracked instance, EF will update the FK behind the scenes. When we start introducing untracked references we start getting errors like "expected 1, affected 0" or duplicate key/FK exceptions.
